# Text center outside of container

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to center the text in css and make it expand from left and right without using javascript and without knowing how big is it?

In my attempts the text always expands to the right.

```css
.container {
  width: 90px;

  border: 1px solid red;
  
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">Hello very long text</div>
  <div class="container">Small text</div>
```

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to understand exact behaviour you are trying to achieve, but if you center text inside your div it will always expand to left and right as much as div width allows it.

Comment: I think you'll need an inner element to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. Thanks to Johannes and VXp for your answer. Flexbox seems nicer to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
.container {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  justify-content: center; /* centers them horizontally */
  width: 90px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Hello very long text</div>
<div class="container">Small text</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is the solution below: Make the container `position: relative`, put a`span` in that and apply the settings below to that span to center it (position: absolute etc.)
You'll have to give some height to the container to make that work though.

```css
.container {
  width: 90px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 1.4em;
}

.container>span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><span>Hello very very very long text</span></div>
<div class="container">Small text</div>
```